# Simple React components won't update after Redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following React component connected to the Redux store, and even though the state of the store changes (I checked), the component prop userIsLogged won't change its value. Any help is appreciated!

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({deauthenticateUser}, dispatch);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ userIsLogged: state.auth.loggedUser !== null });

const Logout = (props) => {

  const { userIsLogged } = props;

  return (
    userIsLogged?
    <Button 
      variant="outlined" 
      color="primary" 
      onClick={(e) => {
        props.deauthenticateUser();
        history.push('/login');
      }}>
      Exit
     </Button>
     :<div />
  );

}

Logout.propTypes = {
  userIsLogged: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Logout);
```

The reducer is as follow:

```
const initialState = {
  jwt: null,
  loggedUser: null,
  isLoading: false
}

export default function auth(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GOT_JWT':
      return Object.assign(state, { jwt: action.jwt });
    case 'USER_LOGGING_IN':
      return Object.assign(initialState, { isLoading: action.isLoading });
    case 'USER_LOGGED_IN':
      return Object.assign(state, { loggedUser: action.loggedUser, isLoading: false });
    case 'NO_JWT':
      return initialState;
    case 'USER_LOGGED_OUT':
      return initialState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: did you follow the data change flow to the component (debugger / breakpoint in `mapStateToProps`... etc)? What happens in your action / reducer?

Comment: Can you post the reducer? You might be mutating the state.

Comment: @MaxMillington Just updated the question.

Comment: @JohnRuddell No, I have been debugging with console.log, haha.

Comment: did you put a console.log inside mapstatetoprops? does the change propagate to that function?

Comment: if you pass `isLoading` to the component, is `isLoading` correctly being passed through?

Comment: You're mutating your state object, instead of creating a new one.

Comment: `Object.assign(state, { jwt: action.jwt });` -> `Object.assign({}, state, { jwt: action.jwt });`, and so on

Comment: @JohnRuddell Yes, I did. The function is being called once, but then the value of state.auth.loggedUser is null, and after the state changes it seems not to be called again. :(

Comment: @zerkms That worked, mate! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer code you're mutating the passed state object.

What happens next is that react treats the state as unchanged (it's the same object), hence it does not re-render it.

To fix it change the

```
Object.assign(state, { jwt: action.jwt });
```

to

```
Object.assign({}, state, { jwt: action.jwt });
```

It would create a new object and copy properties from the original state + the new ones.